# Reports - Is it possible to aggregate a single line of a report?

Tags: reporting

I have a report where revenue is listed depending on the name of the Account.

e.g.

- Company A | 400
- Company B | 600
- Company C | etc

There is a group company with a lot of subsidiaries that I would like to include in the report, except instead of listing each subsidiary as a separate row, I want to aggregate the data so there is just one row for the income from all of the subsidiaries.

*Note:* For reasons I won't go into, we don't have a parent account.

All of the subsidiaries have the same company name somewhere in their name.

So basically, the report needs to show:

- a row for any company with revenue in the period.
- except if the name of the company includes "mycompany" where it should be aggregated into one row.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was add a formula field to the Account object that either returns the company name or, if it includes "mycompany" just returns "mycompany".

Then the reports can be grouped using that formula field, rather than on the Account name.

It can't be scaled ad infinitum, but it's fine for reasonably simple use cases like ours, I think.